# Kivy - Screen Transition Error - AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'manager'

Tags: android, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

In kv file, I have following on_release

```
FlatButton:
                        text: 'Registered User? Sign In'
                        size_hint_y: 0.15
                        on_release:
                            screen_manager.current = "screen_sign_in"
                            root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
```

Error is showing as:  AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'manager'

how to change transition from left to right?

Comment: impossible to tell without seeing more of your `kv` file as a minimum. If you already have a reference to the `ScreenManager` in `screen_manager`, why don't you just use that to set the `transition.direction`? Like `screen_manager.transition.direction = 'right'`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Your suggestion worked. Thanks. I have no idea what root.manager does as I got that by googling.